# How to integrate SCA Stripe Checkout with Stripe Connect using Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, stripe-payments

I've been trying to enable payments to users (sellers in this case) on my site. I've managed to allow the seller to set up their own Stripe account, and then their Stripe account ID is saved in the database.

However, I can't manage to allow people to pay the sellers. I've been looking at the Stripe docs and although very detailed, I can't figure out where everything is meant to go. I would like something like this:

[image: ideal setup]

I have got a new charge view, and this code is supposed to be in it I think:

```
// Initialize Stripe.js with the same connected account ID used when creating
// the Checkout Session.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_CscsJfPdlaNBpLla09y0aA6W', {
  stripeAccount: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}'
});

stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
  // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
  // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
  sessionId: '{{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}}'
}).then(function (result) {
  // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
  // error, display the localized error message to your customer
  // using `result.error.message`.
});
```

I've also got a Charges Controller, but I'm not sure if this is meant to be there:

```
session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
  payment_method_types: ['card'],
  line_items: [{
    name: "Cucumber from Roger's Farm",
    amount: 200,
    currency: 'gbp',
    quantity: 10,
  }],
  payment_intent_data: {
    application_fee_amount: 200,
  },
  success_url: 'https://example.com/success',
  cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel',
}, {stripe_account: '{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}'})
```

How do I Initialize Stripe.js with the right account ID? Where is this code meant to be? Do I need more?

Any help would be massively appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to replace `{{CONNECTED_STRIPE_ACCOUNT_ID}}`, client side and server side, with the appropriate Stripe Account ID.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but is that it? Do I need nothing else in my view?